# Analysis of forecast errors from Facebook Prophet

Tags: forecasting, model-evaluation, diagnostic, acf-pacf, prophet

I created a forecasting model Facebook Prophet and now trying to analyse the forecast errors (yhat - forecasted). Following are 3 graphs I plotted

[image]

[image]

First one is raw forecast errors, second one is their ACF and the last one is residual plot (actual vs forecasted).

Based on ACF plot (2nd plot)

The X axis is the lag 40, and the Y axis is the Pearson’s correlation coefficient at each lag. The blue shaded region is a confidence interval. If the height of the bars is outside this region, it means the correlation is statistically significant and samples are correlated, hence your error/residual is not white noise

Our residual is inside this region hence it is white noise. We can say residuals are independent and identically distributed

In time series forecasting, if the differences between predictions and actual values represent a white noise distribution, one can pat himself on the back for a job well done.

My confusion is with first and third plot, specifically third plot. Do you see any patterns in residuals, as I read if there is any pattern then there is more room to improve your model. Please help me do you see any pattern, further ACF 2nd plot tell me there is white noise in errors, it means the errors does not follow any pattern.

If third plot seems to you has some pattern then why ACF telling me the same there is no pattern (white noise). What to believe for residual analysis? How can I decide about my model stability?

---

Here I am editing with your suggestion

[image: Original Data]

[image: Moving Average]

[image: ACF & Residual Plots]

Comment: What does the first plot show? The raw residuals indexed by time?

Answer (score 4):

The [ACF plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/452368/how-to-understand-an-acf-autocorrelation-plot) *does not* say that the data is "white noise in errors, it means the errors do not follow any pattern". It shows that there is autocorrelation of about 0.6 at lag 1, which is clearly non-zero. This is also what you see on the third plot, there is some autocorrelation in residuals.

Answer (score 3):

Your error terms are not white noise according to the graphs, they are showing a clear pattern. The ACF plot indicates a Moving Average process, MA(1) in this case.

You should also plot the PACF for more information, you will most probably see a gradually declining pattern in the lags of PACF. This will further indicate a MA process.

Your model probably needs one moving average term to eliminate autocorrelation. Then, your error terms will most likely become white noise.

Comment: Thanks Spur and Tim for valuable insights. As far as about ACF plot where 1 lag has some autocorrelation , as per @Spur suggestion do we really need to remove any autocorrelation for any single lag? I read from one of link that "For a white noise series, we expect 95% of the spikes in the ACF to lie within ±2/√T
where T is the length of the time series" ref : [link] https://otexts.com/fpp2/wn.html

Comment: I looked at the link you shared, it also mentions that if any of the spikes are large and outside the bounds. In this case, I would say that the spike is quite significant (close to 0.6). Also, the other graphs do not indicate white noise residuals. My suggestion would be that the model should have a moving average term because the autocorrelation is huge. And, it will most likely give you the white noise errors that you need.

Comment: Thanks @Spur , as I can't share my workaround after following your suggestion here , I edited my original post and shared workaround with your suggestion in the last paragraph with new comments "Here I am editing with your suggestion" You can see autocorrelation has been decreased to 0.5 but still residuals has some pattern

Comment: I am not sure what the first plot shows, but if these are the raw residuals, then MA(1) will not help.

Comment: You should consider both ACF and PACF together to arrive at better insights. If the PACF is gradually declining along with your shown ACF, then MA term will help. I can't really say much without more information on how you obtained the residuals, which model you applied and so on.

Comment: @RichardHardy the first plot is error/residual plot

Comment: @SpurEconomics I got this error plot using Facebook prophet forecasting. I used fb prophet to forecast and then subtract it from actual y target to find residual

Comment: @user172500, I see. The title is kind of misleading, though, as it says *distribution* while actually these are just the residuals themselves (as opposed to a histogram or a kernel density plot). Also, are these residuals or forecast errors? There is a difference. Residuals are in-sample while forecast errors are out of sample.

Comment: @RichardHardy these are forecast errors

Comment: oh, I was under the impression that these are residuals. For forecast errors, analysing the forecast accuracy is the best way to go. You could calculate Mean Absolute Error (MAE) or Mean Absolute Percent Error (MAPE) to check how well your model is doing with out-of-sample forecasts. Your aim could be to minimize the MAE or MAPE, and choose the model giving you minimum error (best out-of-sample forecasts).

Comment: @SpurEconomics actually I am using MAE and r squared metrics for model performance on forecasting out of sample. I am on learning curve , during reading different sources for forecasting I came across one of article where it says "in time series forecasting, if the differences between predictions and actual values represent a white noise distribution, you can pat yourself on the back for a job well done". Do you think we should not consider analysis on forecast errors? https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-detect-random-walk-and-white-noise-in-time-series-forecasting-bdb5bbd4ef81

Comment: That does apply to in-sample predictions, the residuals should be white noise. If they are white noise, your model is good. But when it comes to out-of-sample forecasts and errors, I would just focus on the accuracy of the model. R-square is no good if you want to judge the out-of-sample performance. Rely more on MAE since you are already using it.

Comment: @SpurEconomics why R-square is not good for out of sample?

Comment: By definition, R-square gives us the proportion of variations in the data (in-sample) that are explained by the model. There is no guarantee that a model with a high R-square will perform just as good on another dataset (out-of-sample). Also, a model can have a high R-square because of bias or other problems. In such a case, it will not perform well out of sample. You will need additional measures to judge out-of-sample performance.